# How store methods vals without recreating them every method call

Tags: scala

I have Scala class which methods use a lot of regex. Each class method use some regex patterns.
Looking from the perspective of code modularity I should store those patterns in method:

```
class Bar {
    def foo() {
        val patt1 = "[ab]+".r
        val patt2 = "[cd]+".r
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

But this approach is quite inefficient. Patterns are recompiled on each method call.
I could move them directly to class:

```
class Bar {
    val fooPatt1 = "[ab]+".r
    val fooPatt2 = "[cd]+".r
    /*...*/
}
```

but in case when I have 30 methods it looks ugly.

I ended up with some hybrid solution using val and anonymous function:

```
val z = {
    val patt1 = "[ab]+".r
    val patt2 = "[cd]+".r
    () => { /* ... */ }
}
```

but I am not sure if using val to store function have some drawbacks compared to def. Maybe there is other clean solution to store methods constants without polluting the class?

Comment: If they're constants, the best thing to do would really be to move them to `Bar`'s companion object, which is the closest thing you'll get to Java's `static`. But that makes your code organization problem even worse. It's an unfortunate drawback of the language design, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `val` is perfectly fine. There might be a (very) small performance hit, but in most (99.9%) of the applications that's not a problem.

You could also create a class for the method

```
// The extends is not needed, although you might want to hide the Foo type
class Foo extends (() => ...) {
  val patt1 = "[ab]+".r
  val patt2 = "[cd]+".r

  def apply() = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then in the class:

```
class Bar {
  val foo = new Foo
}
```

Another solution is using traits

```
trait Foo {
  private lazy val patt1 = "[ab]+".r
  private lazy val patt2 = "[cd]+".r

  def foo() = ...
}

class Bar extends Foo with ...
```

Note that if you have different methods like that in a single class, it can be sign that the single responsibility principle is violated. Moving them to their own class (or trait) can be a solution for that problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would put every method with the necessary regex in it's own Trait:

```
class Bar extends AMethod with BMethod

trait AMethod {
  private val aPattern = """\d+""".r   
  def aMethod(s: String) = aPattern.findFirstIn(s)
}

trait BMethod {
  private val bPattern = """\w+""".r
  def bMethod(s: String) = bPattern.findFirstIn(s)
}
```

- clean
- separated
- easy to test (object AMethodSpec extends Properties("AMethod") with AMethod ...)

Comment: You might want to consider the `val` definitions to be private

Comment: yes - or 'private[<PKG>]' for testing purpose. but you're right - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I took into account Chris comment. Putting patterns to companion object is probably the most efficient approach but very unclean when we have more methods.
EECOLOR solution is less efficient but cleaner. Traits prevents recreating patterns on each method call. Unfortunately, scala do not use same compiled pattern accross multiple class instances:

```
(new X).patt1==(new X).patt1 // would be false.
```

I've combined those two approaches and instead traits I used objects.

```
object X {
  object method1 {
    val patt1 = "a".r
  }
  object method2 {
    val patt1 = "a".r
  }
}
class X {
  def method1 = {
    import X.method1._
    patt1
  }
  def method2 = {
    import X.method2._
    patt1
  }
}

(new X).method1 == (new X).method1 // true
(new X).method2 == (new X).method2 // true
```

Although this approach works, I think scala should provide some solution for that problem out of box. Patterns are the simplest example. We could have other immutable objects which initialization is much more expensive.
Extracting method internals somewhere outside is still unclear. It would be nice to do it like with lazy vals. Adding one modificator should ensure that value is instance only once across all instances and methods calls. It would be something like that:

```
def method1 {
 static val  x = new VeryExpensiveObject
}
```